# WooCommerce REST API: List all PARENT orders

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using [WooCommerce REST API](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-orders) to list all orders, but I need to exclude child orders and only fetch parent order. In other words, I need to limit my result to orders which parent_id equals 0. Is it possible to do so using only WC REST API?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the answer was simple.
One of the available parameters in list all orders API is `parent` which does this:

> parent: Limit result set to those of particular parent IDs.

So, if you pass 0 as this parameter's value, you will get all of orders whose parent_id equals 0.